# Facing issue while using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging

I manage an e-commerce website that experiences consistent traffic. To track user activities, we utilize enterprise logging, which is configured through the web.config file. The configuration employs an overwrite mode and sets a maximum file size of 10MB. When the file size limit is not exceeded, a new log file is generated with a random GUID as its filename.

Below script configured under web.config

```
<add name="LJEUTraceListener" formatter="Text Formatter" fileName="..\@data\logs\LJEU\tracelog.txt" timeStampPattern="yyyy-MM-dd" rollSizeKB="10000" rollFileExistsBehavior="Overwrite" rollInterval="None" header="" footer="----------------------------------------" listenerDataType="Sana.Commerce.Tasks.Logging.SanaRollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Sana.Commerce" traceOutputOptions="None" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
```

Please provide a solution to resolve this issue.